# Making delay in camera - kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, delay, android-camerax

I'm trying to make application with camera delay. It should work like this:

- user see preview of live camera
- user choose for example delay 5 sec
- after waiting delay time user see that what camera saw 5 sec ago.

I thought about taking frames from preview and showing them after this delay time, but I'm not sure how to take them and make "movie" from them. 
I was thinking about CameraX but I'm not sure that this is the best option. 
I will really appreciate every help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CameraX as well for your project. Of course I won't go into so much detail but you can follow a path like:

- Do not bind a preview use case and do not use preview view.
- Instead use an Image view or equivalent in which you can set/draw an image.
- Do bind `ImageAnalysis` use case.
- Get the frames for `ImageAnalysis` and then send it directly to be drawn onto the view mentioned above. (Image view might be too expensive, not sure)
- In the above step you can add a delay function to delay drawing as much as you wish.

Of course this is probably not the most effective or elegant way to solve this, but it would work.

Comment: Thank you, can you only explain, how to delay drawing in view?

Comment: You might need a queueing mechanism to store and delay the images. Send the images from analysis to a queue class where you store images and set them to image view with a 5 second delay function. As soon as you set it, you should remove it from memory. Keep in mind that this might be costly and you can try it as very first naive approach. Then you should improve the logic here because, let's say you reach 30 fps, then you should keep 30 frames x 5 seconds = 150 frames in the queue class. Keep the resolution at low so you do not choke the memory.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help